# Turnaround timing: How much below the lead time it should be?

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I have been developping a Matlab Simulink model to a client and it is required the model to be compatible with a time-rate of 1ms. My client will integrate this model with his model parent that runs at this time rate in a multi-core machine.

In spite of this will run a multi-core machine, my model will share a core with other tasks, that means I have more reasons to make sure my model wont consume a lot of processing and cause task overruns.

I believe there is a good practice rule or conceptual definition that estipulates a desired turnaround time depending on lead time. There is?

I wanted to know how much bellow the lead time (1ms) I should worry to keep the turnaround time bellow.

I would appreciate if you could point any reference.

Comment: Having your model share a core, you are asking an impossible question. Assuming the other tasks allocate 99% of the resources,0.02ms is too much. To answer the question if 99% is even realistic, we would have to know about the target and operating system. Assuming everything runs on a windows pc, you definitely won't achieve constant 0.99ms without ever causing a task overrun. And does your client actually run simulink, or is code generated from the model?

Answer (score -2):

if your application needs a precise timing, you should consider a trigger signal send from a hardware, like an arduino, or the internal trigger/timer of the instrument itself. This will not be influenced by the load from your computer.

if you have to use software control, you can use the software to send a trigger signal from serial port. it will more like on-demand mode, but precise time interval is difficult.